# Как получить рейтинг организации yandex.maps?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Я подключаю api без использования ключа api, банальным `https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU` и делаю запрос `ymaps.findOrganization('123456789')`. Я получаю пустой массив с ошибкой "код 3". Я так понимаю, из-за того, что api подключаю без ключа.

Организация, рейтинг который я хочу получить по api, зарегистрирована в яндекс.бизнес. Но я не пойму, как получить ключ к api? И нужен ли он в принципе, что бы выдернуть рейтинг в переменную?

Возможно, я не понимаю некоторой сути, и что-то делаю не так...

Answer (score 0):

[findOrganization](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/findOrganization.html?lang=ru) - не банальный запрос. Это запрос поисковый, тарифицируемый, а значит работать будет только с валидным api-ключом. [Получить ключ](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/quick-start/index.html#get-api-key) несложно в [Кабинете разработчика](https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/).

Обратите внимание, использование [API Карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/) без ключа хоть и может в ряде случаев работать, [пользовательское соглашение](https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/) нарушает. Потому создавать код и надеяться, что он будет стабильно работать в таком режиме недальновидно.

После получения ключа достать рейтинг из ответа сервиса технически возможно. Только сама такая возможность недокументирована, а значит сегодня рейтинг может быть в одном поле, завтра - в другом, послезавтра - убрали.

Лучше используйте готовые виджеты организаций от карт. Они есть разных размеров и функционала: https://jsbin.com/watupunare/1/edit?html,output